# ELGG tools menu items for integrationg to another site

Tags: api, elgg

i need to integrate the elgg tools menu in another website for some kind of use.
Is there any plugins, APIs available for the purpose or can anyone help in creating a new one.

Comment: Well I don't think there is any API related to this, Please Explain what exactly do you need

Comment: I need to get the tools menu in elgg as it is in another external webpage. Its some kind on integration of both the sites .

i just tried to create an api , but its nor working properly . 

Is there any other way than api to achieve this goal ?

Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should create a plugin that will provide the API to other site VIA json or other format,

Please check this API

http://docs.elgg.org/wiki/Web_Services

Comment: yes ai tried for that but its not working :(

Comment: Can  you post the Code here.. or put the plugin for download, so that i can See it..

Comment: Tanks unknown, i had corrected the issue :)